# react native link number doesn't work after #

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-linking

I'm actually trying to link a code like #873766 directly into the phone's calling application.
But only the # appears...
Did you guys have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to encode the USSD code like this :

```
    const ussdCodeEncoded = `tel:${encodeURIComponent(ussdCode)}`
    Linking.openURL("" + ussdCodeEncoded + "")
```